# Evaluate integral $\int\limits_1^\infty x^{y^m}dy$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

What would be the evaluation of the definite integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty x^{y^m}dy$$ where $x$ with $0 < x < 1 $ is real ; $m > 1$ is any integer. At least an approximation will suffice if the error of the approximation is determinable.

Comment: See [Generalized error functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Generalized_error_functions) (non-standard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), this is
$$
\frac{\Gamma(1/m,-\log x)}{m\cdot(-\log x)^{1/m}}.
$$
Hint: Use the change of variable $t=-\log x\cdot y^m$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x \in (0,1)$ this is the same as $1/a$ where $a\in(0,\infty)$ then by some numerical calculations I obtained that $$
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{y^r}\mathrm{d}y=-\frac{1}{r} \cdot \frac{(-1)^{1 - 2/r} \Gamma(1/r)}{\sqrt[r]{\log(a)}} $$
So now you only have to subtract the value of 
$$ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{a}\right)^{y^r} \mathrm{d}y$$
to get your desired integral. The latter integral can be approximated in numerous ways. Although I think a taylor expansion or a sum would suffice.

Comment: Isn't there any exact formula for this later integral too , or must we rely on approximation ?

Comment: dunno, why you askin me bout that?